# how to integrate cloudera apache sentry with open ldap

Tags: security, hadoop, cloudera-quickstart-vm, apache-sentry

I have LDAP in my CDH 5.10 quick start VM for development and I have started the Sentry service within that.

Now I want to integrate Apache Sentry with LDAP.

Please let me know if that is even possible and if yes please guide me through the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to integrate Sentry with LDAP.

The instructions can be found here:

- [Configuring LDAP Group Mappings](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/cm_sg_ldap_grp_mappings.html#concept_lqy_kt4_y4)
- [Using LDAP Username/Password Authentication with HiveServer2](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/cdh_sg_hiveserver2_security.html#topic_9_1_3)
- [Enabling Sentry Authorization for Impala](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/impala_authorization.html#authorization)
- [Configuring the Sentry Service](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-10-x/topics/sg_sentry_service_config.html)

and some links that might be of help are:

- [Need of disabling HiveServer2 Impersonation for sentry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40253712/need-of-disabling-hiveserver2-impersonation-for-sentry/44992454#44992454)
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Batch-SQL-Apache-Hive/Sentry-integration-with-LDAP-Groups/td-p/8514
- https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Security-Apache-Sentry/sentry-ldap-hive-confuse/td-p/37062

Comment: could you please be more specific. I have read through all these links

Comment: Where are you stuck?